# Hide unordered list inside div with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this basic HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="scrollbox list">            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li id="articulate.flute">articulate flute</li>
                <li id="nepalese.ledger">nepalese ledger</li>
                <li id="rural.grass">rural grass</li>
                <li id="alone.fox">alone fox</li>
                <li id="rummage.senator">rummage senator</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a button on the page which hides the `ul` that sits inside the `<div class="scrollbox list">` div.

Is that possible?

Comment: Its not possible until you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `slideToggle()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggleList').click(function(){
    $('.list-unstyled').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="scrollbox list">
          <button class="toggleList"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li id="articulate.flute">articulate flute</li>
                <li id="nepalese.ledger">nepalese ledger</li>
                <li id="rural.grass">rural grass</li>
                <li id="alone.fox">alone fox</li>
                <li id="rummage.senator">rummage senator</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can using jquery like this:

```
$(".scrollbox").find('ul').hide();
```

and if you wand bind above code to you button using this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#buttonName").click(function(){
           $(".scrollbox").find('ul').hide();
    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```js
$(".hide-btn").click(function(){
  $(".list-unstyled").hide();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default hide-btn">hide</button>
        <div class="scrollbox list">            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li id="articulate.flute">articulate flute</li>
                <li id="nepalese.ledger">nepalese ledger</li>
                <li id="rural.grass">rural grass</li>
                <li id="alone.fox">alone fox</li>
                <li id="rummage.senator">rummage senator</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```